# Firebase - how to restrict authenticated user's access to certain paths?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Simple enough question:

How do I restrict paths, such as...

`/orders/<userid>`

`/cart/<userid>`

`/transactions/<userid>/txid`

...only to users whose `userid` matches the one in the path?

I have authentication set up and I need to subscribe to some of these in Vue after `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged`

It appears, as per the docs here, that in the following rule example, the user token must match the key exactly:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does this mean that, `/orders/123456/order123478` will be restricted and only available to user `123456`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the realtime database, update your rules to something like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "orders": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `$uid` key represents any key nested at that level and allows you to reference it in your rules. The `auth` variable is provided by Firebase and contains details about the authenticated user who issued the request, so you can compare the requesting user's `uid` with the database's `uid` key and grant permissions if they match (the nested `".read"` and `".write"` values).

So for a user who's `uid` is `user1`, they would have access to the following data:

```
{
  "orders": {
    "user1": {
      "order1": read/write,
      "order2": read/write
    },
    "user2": {
      "order1": no access,
      "order2": no access
    },
    "user3": {
      "order1": no access,
      "order2": no access
    },
}
```

Read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) and play around with the simulator found in the Rules section of the Firebase dashboard.

Comment: Am I understanding it correctly - the $uid includes every single key all the way from the root?

Comment: @dsp_099 Answer updated. You can also verify your rules using the simulator in the Rules section of the Firebase dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. On a related note, can you think of any cookbook-like github projects with a similar set up? It would be helpful to see how to organize the "schema" so to speak, given this access mechanic

Comment: @dsp_099 No problem...I've been through this learning curve recently and there aren't any one-size-fits-all approaches so you'll just have to experiment and make some mistakes. The Firebase team has some sample apps you can look at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/. And there are a few people who have published articles/videos of how to structure your data in a NoSQL database (sometimes specifically with Firebase) like Chris Esplin: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEd2lEoXpp4.

Comment: Very nice, thanks. One last question: (I'm sure I'll find the answer in the vid eventually) if the data is structured like above, does fetching orders key automatically also pull all the users below it or am I misunderstanding how that works? Should it be instead user, then orders/transactions etc to avoid loading the entire db for every request?